# User Control Textbox - Enable and Disable from ASPX Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am working in C#.Net. I am having ASPX Page and ASCX Page. In my ASCX page, there is a textbox and HTML Image button. I want to do the enable true and false process based on the dropdown selected index changed event. By default, the textbox should be disabled and Image should be visibled false.

Here is my ASPX Page Load..

```
 ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
 PI_CompLocationTree userCntrl = (PI_CompLocationTree)cph.FindControl("PI_CompLocationTree1");
      userCntrl.TextBoxUSC = false;
      userCntrl.ImgUSC = false;

      if (analysisGroup.SelectedValue == "0")
       {
            userCntrl.TextBoxUSC = true;
            userCntrl.ImgUSC = true;
       }
      else if (analysisGroup.SelectedValue == "1")
       {
            userCntrl.TextBoxUSC = true;
            userCntrl.ImgUSC = true;
       }
      else
       {
            userCntrl.TextBoxUSC = false;
            userCntrl.ImgUSC = false;
       }
```

and my ASCX Code..

```
public bool TextBoxUSC
    {
        set { txtLoc.Enabled = value; }
    }
    public bool ImgUSC
    {
        set { imgEdit.Visible = value; }
    }
```

The value are passing correctly to the property. But the textbox control is in disabled mode only and image is in visible false. How to enable and visible the controls.

Comment: You use both `Enabled` and `Visible`, is that a typo in the post?

Comment: yes...i am using enable for textbox and visible for html image...

Comment: I'm curious about the scope of PI_CompLocationTree1?  Is it defined within the aspx page, or are you using nested master pages?  Are you able to access PI_CompLocationTree1 directly from the page without using FindControl?  The best answer may differ depending on these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in `Page_Load` event, do it in `Page_Init` event.

To get the selected value of dropdown list in Page_Init event you can use this approach:

```
if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
        {
            string controlID = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
            if (controlID.Equals(analysisGroup.ID))
            {
                string selectedValue =  Request.Form[Request["__EVENTTARGET"]].ToString();
                Session["SelectedValue"] = selectedValue; //Keep it in session if other controls are also doing post backs.
            }
        }
```

Comment: in page init, i cant able to get the dropdown selected index value...all the time its coming only 0 as the selected index...

Comment: we can address this issue by introducing some javascript code but first run the application in debug mode and set dropdown values manually and see if the required results are coming.

Comment: "Dropdown selectedIndex property is bound after Page_Init event, however before Page_load its value will be loaded from viewstate and its value will be the value which you selected from ddl."       So in your case, write a javascript method and call it on dropdown onchange event, in that event set the selected value in a hidden field and access the value of hidden field in Page_Init event.

Comment: Answer modified showing how to get value of dropdown in Page_Init event.